# check_mk Nagios Plugins

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I am trying to move from Nagios to OMD, however, I have a Nagios plugin which I really need (phpfpm) but I am unable to add the plugin to check_mk.

On the check_mk website says that you should use MRPE however, when I try to run the "cmk" command my OS is complaining that the command doesn't exist.

What you guys are suggesting I could use to run Nagios plugins from OMD?

I am running CentOS with OMD 1.20 installed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to configure `/etc/check_mk/mrpe.cfg` on the host you want to monitor like described in [the CheckMK documentation](https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_mrpe.html). You also need to put your Nagios Plugins on the host you want to monitor.

When you finished that you can run `cmk -I --checks=mrpe host-to-monitor` from OMD. To get to the OMD console of your CheckMK instance use `su - name-of-your-omd-instance`

Answer (score 0):

The files created by OMD are created by Check_mk, in the command file itself, they will clearly say that below commands are generated by the Check_mk, Please don't edit those files.

When you use Nagios alone as a monitoring system, you need to add the host and services from command line.

In case if you are about to go with Check_mk then the host and services can be added in GUI itself.

Create a monitor using command:

sudo omd create MONITER_NAME

sudo omd start monitor

Then in your browser IP_ADDRESS/MONITER_NAME

Default Username: omdadmin
Default Password: omd

If you add the host in the check_mk, it will be reflected in Nagios also.

Please let me know if you're stuck anywhere after this steps.